# If statement is 1 then run specific SQL statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I trying to learn MySQL stored procedures, and I'm stuck in a If..Then matter.
I'm trying to figure out how to show columns do to the matter of a result from the IF.

Here is my code, hope you understand what i'm trying to do, my issue is between "..." and "..." :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_helloworld`()
BEGIN

    SELECT
        ...
        IF pt.is_part_payment = 1 THEN
            pp.due_date AS due_date,
            pp.amount AS amount
        ELSE
            o.due_date AS due_date,
            o.amount AS amount
        END IF;
        ...
    FROM
        orders o
        INNER JOIN payment_types pt ON pt.id = o.payment_type_id 
        INNER JOIN part_payments pp ON pp.order_id = o.order_id
    WHERE
        o.active = 1
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've seen, you can't place an `if` statement in the middle of an SQL query. You could, however, use a `case` expression, although you'd have to do it for each field you're querying separately:

```
SELECT
    ...
    CASE pt.is_part_payment WHEN 1 THEN pp.due_date ELSE o.due_date END
        AS due_date,
    CASE pt.is_part_payment WHEN 1 THEN pp.amount ELSE o.amount END AS amount,
...
FROM
    orders o
    INNER JOIN payment_types pt ON pt.id = o.payment_type_id 
    INNER JOIN part_payments pp ON pp.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE
    o.active = 1
```

Comment: You can also use the `IF()` function.

Comment: I'm looking for the right way to do it in stored procedures, there must be a way to do it "as best practise" ?